# how to convert a set of matrices into a data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have four-time point matrices, A0, A1, A2, and A3, which are m*n matrices. I would like to make a data frame in pandas that involves these matrices and whenever I call them I can access them easily. Is that possible?

For example  `A0=np.array([1,2,3],[3,4,5])`,  `A1=np.array([0,2,0],[3,4,0]),...`
Then when I use `df=pd.DataFrame([A0, A1, A2, A3], columns=['day_0','day_1','day_2','day_3'])`
I got this error that
Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (4, 4).

Comment: can you be more specific on how your matrices looks like ? files, lists, dicts etc...

Comment: they are np.array, like A0=np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(A0)`?

Comment: The problem is that I have four matrices

Comment: do they have the same number of columns ?

Comment: yes, the same number of columns and rows

Answer (score 0):

Well numpy and pandas are compatible in many builtin functions.

```py
import numpy as np
numpy_data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=numpy_data)

# If you know your column names
column_names = ['first_col', 'second_col']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=numpy_data, columns=column_names )
```

So for your example use this then concat all the dataframes.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_A0 = pd.DataFrame(data=A0)
df_A1 = pd.DataFrame(data=A1)
df_A2 = pd.DataFrame(data=A2)
df_A3 = pd.DataFrame(data=A3)

df_names = ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']
df_global = pd.concat([df_A0, df_A1, df_A2, df_A3], keys=df_names)
```

Comment: Then here it df_global is one matrix with 3 columns, what I want is that in df_global, when I want to access A0, recall for example df_global[0] and get A0

Comment: then you want to set some keys, I edited the answer

Comment: No, I want each block to have a name not each column has a name

Comment: well can you show the ouput you want in the question ? Do you want 1 dataframe with them all ? A list of this dataframes ?
Be more precise